# How do I attach to intermediate docker container when building with buildkit

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I recently heard about Buildkit and have been trying to use it with Docker.

I'm using
`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . -t experimental`
to build my Dockerfile.

My `Dockerfile` doesn't build properly because of some missing dependant packages.

What I want to do is to attach to the last working intermediate container and fix the problem with say, `apt` tools.

When building without Buildkit, this would have been possible with the hash values of intermediate containers from the terminal output.

However, the output from Buildkit is not providing me such values. So, is there any way for me to access them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it is not possible at the moment see [buildkit/issue#1472](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1472).

But BuildKit still caches all layers so you could use a work around.

- Inspecting the image **before** the failing `RUN` command, comment out the failing and all subsequent `RUN` commands. Rerun `docker build` and then do `docker run` to inspect the image.
- Inspecting the image **after** the failing `RUN` command, add `|| true` at the end of your `RUN` command to force the command to succeed. Rerun `docker build` and then do `docker run` to inspect the image.

Comment: The ticket mentioned has been closed. This is the relevant one now: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1472 

PS. I can't edit because the edit queue is full

Comment: Nice trick! Thx!