# How do we run from an intermediary layer with docker buildkit?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

With non buildkit mode, when we build, we have this sort of output:

```
...
Step 38/43 : COPY tests .
 ---> d201e365ba86
Step 39/43 : COPY tools .
 ---> 13d191aa76c1
Step 40/43 : COPY tox.ini .
 ---> 4173ecd8eae9
...
```

If it fails somewhere, we can simply run from these intermediary layer by using the hashes with something like `docker run -ti 13d191aa76c1 bash`.

I can't find how to do the same with buildkit enabled. While using the `--progress=plain` flag, I see the following sort of output

```
...
#32 [28/33] COPY test.py .
#32 sha256:bee3b0d9d9187a03f8652903f0aaf3340246f7f70788fdfcac381c3a970491e3
#32 CACHED
...
```

Is there a way we can run on that intermediary layer the same way we can without buildkit? How can we use that sha256 identifier?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/q/60923893/11715259 , isn't it?